# How to know in advance if data would fit in a DataSet

Tags: oracle, delphi, dataset

I´m maintaining an old Delphi 7 App using Allround Automations' DOA 4 to access an Oracle DB.
The app has an adhoc configurable reporter unit that sometimes fails because data selected from the DB won't fit in the TOracleDataSet. My question is how to know in advance if the data would fit.
I tried running a count(*) query first which multiplied by DataSet.recordsize gives me the data volume I had to allocate. But I don´t know how much memory is available to get the data or if that memory is limited by the dataset component.

Greetings, Marcelo.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask Allround Automations questions about the capabilities of their TOracleDataSet instead of us? They wrote it.

Comment: What do you mean by "wont fit"? Do you get errors, is it just truncated?

Comment: @Nat: If the poster is trying to use *count(*) multiplied by recordsize*, it's not a truncation issue.

Comment: @KenWhite TOracleDataSet should be allocating the memory itself, surely based on exactly that information. My question was to try to work out if the problem was a memory limit or something wrong with the SQL...